# Iterate through loaded HTML file elements JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a website. The header is loaded into the main 'search' page using the .load() function from JQuery. However, when I try to iterate through the [href]'s in the page, it cannot find them because the loaded header links haven't been added to the DOM yet (presumably).

```
function getCurrentPage(){
        var count = 0;
        $(".navLinks").each(function() {
            count+=1
            console.log('this.href' + this.href)
            console.log('windowloc' + window.location.href)
            if (this.href == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
        console.log('# of hrefs' + count)
    }
```

This is a function I wrote to add a css class to the current page, but this loop wont work since it cannot find those on the DOM (the .navLinks class is added to all links thats from the loaded header.html file). Thanks for the help!

```
<header>
<nav class="top-bar nav-desktop">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <div class="logo">
                <img class="logo-image" src="repairrepo_logo-02.png" width="250" height="184"></img>
                <p class="site-logo">DNA Damage and Repair Database</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu menu-desktop">
                <li><a href="index.html" class = 'navLinks'>HOME </a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">BROWSE
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#" class = 'navLinks'>HUMAN </a>
                            <a href="#" class = 'navLinks'>MOUSE</a>
                            <a href="#" class = 'navLinks'>ARABIDOPSIS</a>
                            <a href="#" class = 'navLinks'>PLANT</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="search.html" class = 'navLinks'>SEARCH</a></li>
                <li><a href="download.html" class = 'navLinks'>DOWNLOAD</a></li>
                <li><a href="help.html" class = 'navLinks'>HELP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the 'header.html' file that is added and appended to a div with id 'header' on the main search page.

Comment: when and how do you call `getCurrentPage()`  ?

Comment: I just call it right after document.ready in my jquery script

Answer (score 0):

you guessed it right,

> it cannot find them because the loaded header links haven't been added to the DOM yet

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous and has a callback that executes when it's done, that's where you should call your function :

```
$('#someDiv').load('someHtml.html', getCurrentPage);
```

note that you have to passe the function by reference ( wihtout `()` ) otherwise it will be executed before the `load()` is done.

Comment: So I placed this in the beginning of the js script, but the 'count' variable is still printing out 0...

Comment: add the related `html` for more accurate answer

Comment: what do you get if you put just `console.log('count : ', $('.navLinks').length)` in the `getCurrentPage` function ?